# Which 6950 XT graphic card brand is better

Tags: graphics-cards

Which 6950xt is best so many companies have their models like **Gigabyte Radeon RX 6950 XT Gaming OC**,
MSI Radeon RX 6950 XT Gaming X Trio,**xfx**, and **Sapphire Radeon RX 6950 XT Nitro+ Pure** many more can anyone suggest which is best

Comment: I have an XFX (not RX 6950XT though, RX 570 8GB) and it's pretty good (#1 night raid for 1x RX570 and R3 3100)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with the Asrock OC Formula Radeon rx 6950xt. Its based off the one of the best 6900xt cards. There are videos on Youtube breaking down the PCB's of the 6900xt and 6950xt's and Asrock was one of the best PCB's. The video channel is called Actually Hardcore Overclocking